# Assigning Loop Number to a Phrase

Tags: coldfusion

I have a dropdown on my first page that allows the user to choose a number 1 - 5.

I assign the dropdown(pcount) to a session variable like this:

```
<cfparam name="form.pcount" default="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#">
```

My very next page then loops that many times like this:

```
 <cfset Peoplecount = 1>
        <cfloop index="Add" from="1" to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#" step="1">
                <cfset session.checkout.info["firstname_#Add#"]="">

<cfset Peoplecount = PeopleCount + 1>
```

And my html:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Owner <cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>'s Information</legend>

<div class="clearfix">
    <label for="firstname_<cfoutput>#Add#</cfoutput>">Owner <cfoutput>#Peoplecount#</cfoutput>'s Name As It Appears on Driver License:</label>
```

The way it works now is the legend will show Owner 1's Information. My issue is the number just looks ridiculous I prefer to be able to set 1 to equal First so that it shows First Owner, Second Owner, Third Owner, Instead of Owner 1 , Owner 2, Owner 3. And I cannot assign 1 in general to equal First because the number 1 and 2 are being used throughout the page as well. Does anyone have an easy way of doing this?

Comment: You can create a comma delimited list at your page with all values like `First,Second.....` and output `listgetat(list name, peoplecount  ",")`. This can be a way.

Comment: You might want to look at this custom tag: http://www.cflib.org/udf/CardinalToOrdinal

Comment: @duncan that works the opposite of what he's looking for

Comment: I'd use something similar to what @Beginner suggested. Try this for example: http://trycf.com/editor/gist/e2212cf03754bd86cf38/acf11?theme=solarized_dark

Comment: @Matt I haven't tried it myself, but judging from the name of the UDF it should convert 1 to 'first' and so on. Which I think is what Zane's asking for

Comment: @duncan if you look at the example on that page that's not what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet assuming the count can't up too high is to create an array to pull in the name

```
numberMapping = ['First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth','Sixth'];
```

Then update your owner to pull based on your array

```
<legend>Owner <cfoutput>#numberMapping[Peoplecount]#</cfoutput>'s Information</legend>
```

Comment: so I need to put the array inside script tags?

Comment: or you could use a `cfset`

Comment: <cfset numberMapping = ['First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth','Sixth']; > similar to this?

Comment: It'd be best to start putting that stuff in cfscript, but `<cfset numberMapping = ['First','Second','Third','Fourth','Fifth','Sixth']; >` will do